# SQL - retrieve last record of day for the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am inserting a record every hour into my table. Now I need to retrieve the most recent record of each day for the last 30 days.

Here is my table:

```
pl_scores: {
  score_id: 'BIGINT(255) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT'
, pid: 'INT(100)'
, score: 'INT(255)'
, rank: 'INT(50)'
, city_cnt: 'INT(10)'
, updatedAt: 'DATETIME'
}
```

Since there is 24 records for each day I am at a loss as to how to pull the most recent only  for that day. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1 - Break them into groups by day.
Step 2 - Select the timestamp of the last entry for each group.
Step 3 - Go back and get the records that match those timestamps.

```
SELECT
  pl_scores.*
FROM
  pl_scores
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(updatedAt) AS maxUpdatedAt FROM pl_scores GROUP BY DATE(updatedAt)) as Lookup
    ON Lookup.MaxUpdatedAt = pl_scores.updatedAt
```

Note:  This assumes that each record has a different value in updatedAt.  If they're not unique, and multiple records are tied for being the most recent on any given day, all the tied records are returned.

Comment: Sorry, saved before I was finished.  Ooops.  Done now :)

Comment: So I can just add an order by and limit to select the last 30 days or 7 days, correct?

Comment: @PastorBones - Yep.  Although you may see better performance using `WHERE updatedAt >= 'from date here'`.  That will also guarantee the number of days rather than the number of records.  (In case no records got inserted on Christmas day, for example.)